# Publish ClickOnce to UNC path with alternative credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I have an application which is published using ClickOnce deployment to a fileserver, and this works fine.  I now have the need to deploy this application to another one of our offices which is on a completely different domain.  I can connect to a UNC path, or map a network drive to the path where this needs to be deployed (using different credentials provided by the domain admin) however I cannot publish my ClickOnce to this path as it claims it is not accessible.  I assume that this is due to it being published using my default windows identity which not being on the domain does not have access to this path.

I need to publish to this path (due to the well documented issues around not being able to publish and copy auto updating ClickOnce deploys), is there any way I can specify different credentials when publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end just ended up deploying locally, making any required changes to the manifest using MageUI and copying over